# How to add to a data frame values calculated from values in another data frame using complex formulas and time conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a dataframe `df` that has detections of different individuals of a specific species over time (`DateTime`). Each individual is identified by the `ID` column. As an example:

```
df<- data.frame(DateTime=c("2017-08-05 14:03:55.300","2017-08-05 16:18:12.100","2017-08-05 20:34:31.540","2017-08-05 16:18:14.355","2017-08-05 20:34:33.605"),
    ID= c("A","B","C","B","C"))

df
                 DateTime ID
1 2017-08-05 14:03:55.300  A
2 2017-08-05 16:18:12.100  B
3 2017-08-05 20:34:31.540  C
4 2017-08-05 16:18:14.355  B
5 2017-08-05 20:34:33.605  C
```

I have other dataframe called `Activity` which contains acceleration data about those individuals (`ID`) over time (`DateTime`). To those who don't know what acceleration data is, It is a measure of acceleration of the individuals in the three-axis of the space (x, y, z) at a high frequency (11 data per second). I tried to make a reproducible example:

```
options("digits.secs" = 3)
set.seed(100)
fmt <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"
df<- data.frame(DateTime=c("2017-08-05 14:03:55.300","2017-08-05 16:18:12.100","2017-08-05 20:34:31.540","2017-08-05 16:18:14.355","2017-08-05 20:34:33.605"),
                ID= c("A","B","C","B","C"))

DateTime = seq(from=as.POSIXct("2017-08-05 14:03:55.300", format=fmt, tz="UTC"), by=1/11, length.out=67)
ID = rep("A", each=67)
x= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 67, replace = TRUE)
y= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 67, replace = TRUE)
z= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 67, replace = TRUE)
Activity1<- data.frame(DateTime,ID, x, y, z)

DateTime = seq(from=as.POSIXct("2017-08-05 16:18:12.100", format=fmt, tz="UTC"),by=1/11, length.out=67)
ID = rep("B", each=67)
x= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 67, replace = TRUE)
y= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 67, replace = TRUE)
z= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 67, replace = TRUE)
Activity2<- data.frame(DateTime,ID, x, y, z)

DateTime = seq(from=as.POSIXct("2017-08-05 20:34:31.540", format=fmt, tz="UTC"),by=1/11, length.out=67)
ID = rep("C", each=67)
x= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 67, replace = TRUE)
y= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 67, replace = TRUE)
z= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 67, replace = TRUE)
Activity3<- data.frame(DateTime,ID, x, y, z)
Activity<- rbind(Activity1,Activity2,Activity3)


head(Activity)

                 DateTime ID     x     y     z
1 2017-08-05 14:03:55.299  A  0.01  0.82 -0.56
2 2017-08-05 14:03:55.390  A  0.11  0.74  0.07
3 2017-08-05 14:03:55.481  A  0.50  0.95 -0.64
4 2017-08-05 14:03:55.572  A  0.97 -0.89  0.95
5 2017-08-05 14:03:55.663  A -0.97  0.78 -0.01
6 2017-08-05 14:03:55.754  A -0.46  0.20  1.00
```

I would like to add two variables called `VeDBA` and `RMS` ("Root Mean square") to the dataframe `df`. Those variables are indicative of the activity of the animals, thus, we use data from the dataframe `Activity`. Either for `VeDBA` and for `RMS` we use two seconds of data using as starting point the `DateTime` that appears in the dataframe `df`. Since we have 11 records per second in the dataframe `Activity`, two seconds mean 22 rows of data from the dataframe `Activity`. The difference between `VeDBA` and `RMS` is:

1. VeDBA. We make the square root of the sum of the squares of X, Y and Z per row. Then we add up the 22 rows of data that cover the time interval that starts where "DateTime" is indicated in "DF" and divide it by the number of records (22) to make an average. For instance, I calculated manually the `VeDBA` value for the first row of the dataframe `df`. Here the code and the result:

```
Vector1<-Activity1[Activity1$DateTime >= "2017-08-05 16:03:55.300" & Activity1$DateTime <= "2017-08-05 16:03:57.300",c("x","y","z")]
head(Vector1)
VeDBA1<-((Vector1$x)^2 + (Vector1$y)^2 + (Vector1$z)^2)^(1/2)
VeDBAmean<- sum(VeDBA1)/length(VeDBA1)

VeDBAmean
[1] 1.113272
```

2. RMS. Here the calculation is different. First, we add up the squared values of the 2-second interval starting immediately after the 'DateTime' in 'DF' per axis (X, Y, Z). Then we divide it by the number of rows in the time interval (=22). Then we add up the average value of the 3 axes and make the square root. For instance, I calculated manually the `RMS` value for the first row of the dataframe `df`. Here the code and the result:

```
Value1x<- Activity1[Activity1$DateTime >= "2017-08-05 16:03:55.300" & Activity1$DateTime <= "2017-08-05 16:03:57.300",c("x")]
Value1y<- Activity1[Activity1$DateTime >= "2017-08-05 16:03:55.300" & Activity1$DateTime <= "2017-08-05 16:03:57.300",c("y")]
Value1z<- Activity1[Activity1$DateTime >= "2017-08-05 16:03:55.300" & Activity1$DateTime <= "2017-08-05 16:03:57.300",c("z")]

Value1xsquared<-Value1x^2
Value1ysquared<-Value1y^2
Value1zsquared<-Value1z^2

Ax1<-sum(Value1xsquared)/length(Value1xsquared)    
Ay1<-sum(Value1ysquared)/length(Value1ysquared)
Az1<-sum(Value1zsquared)/length(Value1zsquared) 

RMS1 <- sqrt(Ax1 + Ay1 + Az1)

RMS1
[1] 5.331801
```

My problem is that my real dataframe `df` has more than 7000 rows and I cant calculate those values manually per row. I would like to use a code that automatically calculates these values.

Here I show the theoretical result for the unreal dataframe `df`:

```
> df
                 DateTime ID     VeDBA      RMS
1 2017-08-05 14:03:55.300  A 1.1132721 5.331801
2 2017-08-05 16:18:12.100  B 0.9088045 4.464616
3 2017-08-05 20:34:31.540  C 1.0759847 5.137859
4 2017-08-05 16:18:14.355  B 0.9643981 4.698032
5 2017-08-05 20:34:33.605  C 0.9208489 4.492460
```

Does anyone know how to calculate these two values quickly?

Note: With my real data I will use a different interval of time. That is, instead of 2 seconds I will use 57 seconds but for reproducibility purposes I used a shorter period.

Comment: Hi @akrun. `Activity1`, `Activity2` and `Activity3` were created in order to create the final dataframe `Activity`. Each dataframe has the data for a different individual and I merge them all finally in `Activity`. I didn't know how to do it in a different way. The dataframe you have to use is `Activity`.

Comment: I think @akrun means there is no `2017-08-05 16:03:55.300` in your sample data and you do your calculations using that time in the VeDBA and RMS explanations. There is a `2017-08-05 14:03:55.300` in your sample data.

Comment: I use the time `"2017-08-05 16:03:55.300"` in my code to calculate either `VeDBA` or `RMS` because I don't know why, but I have verified that to the time that I want, between quotes I must add two hours by matters of format of date and hour. If I were to put "2017-08-05 14:03:55,300" in quotes, then R would not find in the 'Activity' dataframe a matching time interval for the same individual and same time. Is that understood?

Comment: It will be easier to help, and for you to debug as well, if you heed the *minimal* part of the [mcve] guidance. There's a lot of code here, and a lot of places where code is doing very similar things multiple times. Can you try to pare this down to the essentials?

Comment: Thanks Camille. I will use the code used for @chinsoon12 in his example just in case someone else wants to share a different way of calculating what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to use a non-equi join in `data.table` and then calculate desired output for each row of `df`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, DateTime := as.POSIXct(DateTime, format=fmt, tz="UTC")][,
    c("start", "end") := .(DateTime, DateTime+2)]
setDT(Activity)[, DateTime := as.POSIXct(DateTime, format=fmt, tz="UTC")]

Activity[df, on=.(ID, DateTime>=start, DateTime<=end),
    by=.EACHI, .(
        DateTime=i.DateTime,
        ID=i.ID, 
        VeDBA=sum(sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)) / .N,
        RMS=sqrt((sum(x^2) + sum(y^2) + sum(z^2)) / .N))][, 
            (1L:3L) := NULL][]
```

output:

```
                  DateTime ID     VeDBA       RMS
1: 2017-08-05 14:03:55.299  A 1.1132721 1.1334039
2: 2017-08-05 16:18:12.099  B 0.9079014 0.9491736
3: 2017-08-05 20:34:31.539  C 1.0685788 1.0878339
4: 2017-08-05 16:18:14.355  B 0.9643981 1.0016237
5: 2017-08-05 20:34:33.605  C 0.9208489 0.9577958
```

I think there is quite a number of consistency issues with your dataset and have gone ahead and create another one:

```
set.seed(100)
fmt <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"
df<- data.frame(DateTime=c("2017-08-05 14:03:55.300","2017-08-05 16:18:12.100","2017-08-05 20:34:31.540","2017-08-05 16:18:14.355","2017-08-05 20:34:33.605"),
    ID= c("A","B","C","B","C"))

DateTime = seq(from=as.POSIXct("2017-08-05 14:03:55.300", format=fmt, tz="UTC"), by=1/11, length.out=67)
ID = rep("A", each=67)
x= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 67, replace = TRUE)
y= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 67, replace = TRUE)
z= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 67, replace = TRUE)
Activity1<- data.frame(DateTime,ID, x, y, z)

DateTime = seq(from=as.POSIXct("2017-08-05 16:18:12.100", format=fmt, tz="UTC"),by=1/11, length.out=67)
ID = rep("B", each=67)
x= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 67, replace = TRUE)
y= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 67, replace = TRUE)
z= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 67, replace = TRUE)
Activity2<- data.frame(DateTime,ID, x, y, z)

DateTime = seq(from=as.POSIXct("2017-08-05 20:34:31.540", format=fmt, tz="UTC"),by=1/11, length.out=67)
ID = rep("C", each=67)
x= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 67, replace = TRUE)
y= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 67, replace = TRUE)
z= sample(seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.01), size = 67, replace = TRUE)
Activity3<- data.frame(DateTime,ID, x, y, z)
Activity<- rbind(Activity1,Activity2,Activity3)

Activity


Vector1<-Activity1[Activity1$DateTime >= as.POSIXct("2017-08-05 14:03:55.300", format=fmt, tz="UTC") & 
        Activity1$DateTime <= as.POSIXct("2017-08-05 14:03:57.300", format=fmt, tz="UTC"),
    c("x","y","z")]
head(Vector1)
VeDBA1<-((Vector1$x)^2 + (Vector1$y)^2 + (Vector1$z)^2)^(1/2)
VeDBAmean<- sum(VeDBA1)/length(VeDBA1)
VeDBAmean
#[1] 1.113272
```

---

raw data:

```
Activity <- structure(list(DateTime = structure(c(1501941835.3, 1501941835.39091, 
1501941835.48182, 1501941835.57273, 1501941835.66364, 1501941835.75455, 
1501941835.84545, 1501941835.93636, 1501941836.02727, 1501941836.11818, 
1501941836.20909, 1501941836.3, 1501941836.39091, 1501941836.48182, 
1501941836.57273, 1501941836.66364, 1501941836.75455, 1501941836.84545, 
1501941836.93636, 1501941837.02727, 1501941837.11818, 1501941837.20909, 
1501941837.3, 1501941837.39091, 1501941837.48182, 1501941837.57273, 
1501941837.66364, 1501941837.75455, 1501941837.84545, 1501941837.93636, 
1501941838.02727, 1501941838.11818, 1501941838.20909, 1501941838.3, 
1501941838.39091, 1501941838.48182, 1501941838.57273, 1501941838.66364, 
1501941838.75455, 1501941838.84545, 1501941838.93636, 1501941839.02727, 
1501941839.11818, 1501941839.20909, 1501941839.3, 1501941839.39091, 
1501941839.48182, 1501941839.57273, 1501941839.66364, 1501941839.75455, 
1501941839.84545, 1501941839.93636, 1501941840.02727, 1501941840.11818, 
1501941840.20909, 1501941840.3, 1501941840.39091, 1501941840.48182, 
1501941840.57273, 1501941840.66364, 1501941840.75455, 1501941840.84545, 
1501941840.93636, 1501941841.02727, 1501941841.11818, 1501941841.20909, 
1501941841.3, 1501949892.1, 1501949892.19091, 1501949892.28182, 
1501949892.37273, 1501949892.46364, 1501949892.55455, 1501949892.64545, 
1501949892.73636, 1501949892.82727, 1501949892.91818, 1501949893.00909, 
1501949893.1, 1501949893.19091, 1501949893.28182, 1501949893.37273, 
1501949893.46364, 1501949893.55455, 1501949893.64545, 1501949893.73636, 
1501949893.82727, 1501949893.91818, 1501949894.00909, 1501949894.1, 
1501949894.19091, 1501949894.28182, 1501949894.37273, 1501949894.46364, 
1501949894.55455, 1501949894.64545, 1501949894.73636, 1501949894.82727, 
1501949894.91818, 1501949895.00909, 1501949895.1, 1501949895.19091, 
1501949895.28182, 1501949895.37273, 1501949895.46364, 1501949895.55455, 
1501949895.64545, 1501949895.73636, 1501949895.82727, 1501949895.91818, 
1501949896.00909, 1501949896.1, 1501949896.19091, 1501949896.28182, 
1501949896.37273, 1501949896.46364, 1501949896.55455, 1501949896.64545, 
1501949896.73636, 1501949896.82727, 1501949896.91818, 1501949897.00909, 
1501949897.1, 1501949897.19091, 1501949897.28182, 1501949897.37273, 
1501949897.46364, 1501949897.55455, 1501949897.64545, 1501949897.73636, 
1501949897.82727, 1501949897.91818, 1501949898.00909, 1501949898.1, 
1501965271.54, 1501965271.63091, 1501965271.72182, 1501965271.81273, 
1501965271.90364, 1501965271.99455, 1501965272.08545, 1501965272.17636, 
1501965272.26727, 1501965272.35818, 1501965272.44909, 1501965272.54, 
1501965272.63091, 1501965272.72182, 1501965272.81273, 1501965272.90364, 
1501965272.99455, 1501965273.08545, 1501965273.17636, 1501965273.26727, 
1501965273.35818, 1501965273.44909, 1501965273.54, 1501965273.63091, 
1501965273.72182, 1501965273.81273, 1501965273.90364, 1501965273.99455, 
1501965274.08545, 1501965274.17636, 1501965274.26727, 1501965274.35818, 
1501965274.44909, 1501965274.54, 1501965274.63091, 1501965274.72182, 
1501965274.81273, 1501965274.90364, 1501965274.99455, 1501965275.08545, 
1501965275.17636, 1501965275.26727, 1501965275.35818, 1501965275.44909, 
1501965275.54, 1501965275.63091, 1501965275.72182, 1501965275.81273, 
1501965275.90364, 1501965275.99455, 1501965276.08545, 1501965276.17636, 
1501965276.26727, 1501965276.35818, 1501965276.44909, 1501965276.54, 
1501965276.63091, 1501965276.72182, 1501965276.81273, 1501965276.90364, 
1501965276.99455, 1501965277.08545, 1501965277.17636, 1501965277.26727, 
1501965277.35818, 1501965277.44909, 1501965277.54), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"
), x = c(0.01, 0.11, 0.5, 0.97, -0.97, -0.46, -0.31, -0.03, 0.34, 
-0.94, 0.82, -0.58, 0.88, 0.39, -0.5, 0.99, 0.45, -0.76, -0.99, 
0.78, -0.33, -0.33, 0.79, -0.53, -0.69, -0.16, -0.1, 0.66, 0.2, 
-0.85, 0.15, 0.93, 0.97, -0.08, -0.56, 0.57, 0.57, -0.14, -0.0599999999999999, 
-0.04, 0.56, -0.7, 0.81, 0.68, -0.6, 0.51, 0.7, -0.94, 0.9, 0.92, 
0.36, 0.47, 0.41, 0.0600000000000001, -0.23, -0.13, 0.3, 0.0900000000000001, 
0.63, 0.14, 0.14, 0.54, 0.73, 0.86, 0.73, 0.96, -0.54, 0.55, 
-0.85, -0.32, 0.34, 0.83, 0.64, 0.15, -0.29, -0.96, -0.17, 0.0700000000000001, 
-0.55, 0.15, -0.81, -0.45, 0.92, -0.65, -0.63, 0.83, -0.58, 0.38, 
-0.4, 0.46, 0.17, 0.69, -0.87, 0.26, -0.43, 0.0900000000000001, 
-0.98, -0.58, 0.35, 0.85, -0.25, 0.47, -0.46, 0.14, -0.76, -0.53, 
0.69, -0.53, -0.62, 0.27, 0.9, -0.94, -0.6, -0.0599999999999999, 
-0.82, 0.76, -0.03, 0.76, 0.29, 0.24, 0.81, -0.45, 0.39, 0.26, 
-0.65, 0.36, 0.28, -0.14, 0.1, 0.4, 0.82, -0.58, -0.6, -0.3, 
-0.85, 0.6, 0.69, -0.79, 0.0700000000000001, -0.04, 0.47, 0.72, 
0.86, 0.74, 0.31, -0.9, -0.22, 0.85, -0.81, 0.61, 0.54, -0.0599999999999999, 
-0.04, 0.5, -0.92, -1, -0.61, -0.18, 0.01, 0.66, 0.85, 0.54, 
-0.81, -0.18, 0.84, -0.32, -0.61, -0.52, -0.12, 0.22, 0.9, 0.91, 
0.64, -0.27, -0.18, -0.2, 0.15, 0.58, 0.12, 0.01, -0.8, 0, -0.95, 
-0.46, -0.36, -0.24, -0.11, 0.72, 0.53, -0.32, 0.69, 0.96, -0.83, 
-0.67, 0.03, 0.21, -0.83, -0.62, -0.51, -0.16, -0.65), y = c(0.82, 
0.74, 0.95, -0.89, 0.78, 0.2, -0.85, 0.83, 0.49, 0.8, 0.3, 0.32, 
-0.57, -0.16, 0.55, 0.79, -0.76, -0.59, 0.42, 0.84, -0.59, -0.25, 
0.64, 0.53, 0.02, -0.77, 0.39, 0.36, 0.0600000000000001, -0.46, 
-0.26, 0.9, -0.66, -0.43, -0.75, -0.53, -0.21, 0.17, -0.64, 0.45, 
-0.29, -0.1, -0.29, 0.93, 0.46, -0.0599999999999999, 0.5, -0.25, 
-0.75, -0.96, -0.23, -0.61, 0.1, -0.2, -0.25, 0.91, 0.81, 0.69, 
0.3, -0.21, 0.65, 0.7, 0.31, -0.51, -0.89, 0.26, -0.41, 0.0600000000000001, 
-0.25, -0.32, 0.96, -0.4, 0.85, -0.63, 0.17, 0.35, 0.72, -0.03, 
0.62, 0.34, 0.29, 0.02, 0.82, 0.26, -0.45, -0.28, 0.74, 0.35, 
0.54, -0.73, -0.89, 0.0600000000000001, 0.66, 0.31, 0.18, -0.58, 
-0.61, 0.45, 0.12, 0.02, -0.33, 0.44, 0.19, 0.4, -0.02, -0.78, 
-0.76, -0.16, -0.99, 0.49, -0.3, -0.45, -0.89, 0.28, -0.19, -0.24, 
0.77, 0.32, 0.67, 0.9, -0.18, -0.68, -0.17, 0.29, 0.9, -0.61, 
0.25, -0.64, 0.43, 0.27, 0.0900000000000001, 0.78, -0.8, 0.14, 
-0.11, 0.33, 0.6, 0.73, 0.43, -0.09, 0.68, -0.88, -0.45, -0.88, 
0.41, 0.82, 0.99, 0.57, -0.27, -0.56, -0.66, 0.9, 0.71, 0.44, 
-0.53, -0.25, -0.16, 0.66, -0.07, 0.28, -0.29, -0.04, 0.68, -0.42, 
-0.28, 0.11, 0.1, -0.22, -0.89, 0.15, -0.11, -0.96, 0.33, -0.6, 
-0.97, -0.37, 0.35, 0.43, 0.87, -0.76, 0.8, -0.94, -0.83, -0.11, 
-0.47, -0.61, 0.62, -0.38, 0.36, -0.33, -0.7, 0.59, 0.23, -0.22, 
0.15, -0.18, -0.56, -0.64, 0.19, -0.48, -0.74), z = c(-0.56, 
0.0700000000000001, -0.64, 0.95, -0.01, 1, 0.53, -0.74, 0.58, 
0.73, -0.3, 0.48, -0.62, 0.92, -0.85, -0.19, 0.35, 0.37, 0.96, 
0.57, 0.98, 0.76, 0.29, 0.38, -0.54, 0.13, -1, -0.69, 1, 0.24, 
0.2, -0.88, -0.39, 0.38, -0.01, 0.85, 0.41, 0.69, 0.47, -0.37, 
-0.86, -0.81, 0.77, 0.27, -0.54, 0.82, 0.45, 0.25, 0.01, -0.48, 
-0.17, -0.9, 0.49, -0.14, -0.49, 0.27, 0.66, 0.58, -0.23, -0.55, 
0.91, 0.46, 0.38, 0.47, -0.27, -0.55, -0.19, 0.21, 0.45, 0.72, 
0.18, -0.87, -0.04, -0.56, 0.32, 0.14, 0.43, 0.13, 0.84, -0.75, 
0.64, 0.28, 0.86, -0.35, 0.73, 0.48, -0.08, 0.96, -0.49, -0.21, 
-0.2, -0.17, 0.87, -0.7, 0.17, 0.68, -0.97, -0.95, -0.22, 0.29, 
-0.69, 0.03, -0.8, 0.85, 0.16, -0.88, -0.84, -0.76, -0.25, -0.54, 
-0.27, 0.05, -0.2, -0.76, -0.74, -0.53, -0.57, 0.37, 0.85, 0.16, 
-0.31, 0.57, 0.34, -0.03, -0.37, -0.17, 0.93, 0.66, 0.32, -0.86, 
-0.97, 0.87, -0.13, -0.75, -0.44, -0.93, -0.87, -0.71, -0.57, 
0.91, -0.4, -0.7, 0.39, 1, 0.73, -0.35, 0.33, -0.47, 0.71, -0.9, 
-0.6, -0.53, -0.24, -0.23, -0.7, 0.17, 0.65, -0.36, 0.44, 0.43, 
0.35, -0.69, -0.19, 0.57, 0.67, -0.77, -0.08, 0.49, 0.8, 0.37, 
0.92, 0.65, 0.73, -0.57, -0.98, -0.75, -0.59, -0.79, -0.16, -0.04, 
0.46, -0.82, -0.93, 0.03, -0.36, 0.23, 0.99, 0.97, 0.49, 0.22, 
-0.65, 0.57, 0.21, 0.49, 0.8, -0.48, 0.52, 0.86, -0.43, -0.77, 
-0.09)), row.names = c(NA, -201L), class = "data.frame")


df <- structure(list(DateTime = structure(c(1501941835.3, 1501949892.1, 
1501965271.54, 1501949894.355, 1501965273.605), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), ID = c("A", "B", "C", "B", "C"), start = structure(c(1501941835.3, 
1501949892.1, 1501965271.54, 1501949894.355, 1501965273.605), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), end = structure(c(1501941837.3, 1501949894.1, 
1501965273.54, 1501949896.355, 1501965275.605), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Thanks @chinsoon12. It looks like it works. However, there is something I don't understand. When I copy your code and I run it, I get something different for VeDBA and RMS. For instance, for VeDBA in `df` I get `0.917` instead of `1.113272` (1st row). I don't know if it might be related to the time format or what. For RMS I get `0.968` instead of `1.1334039` (1st row). Do you know why is this happening? I have checked that my `Activity` dataframe and yours is the same. So the problem should be other. I ask you because the difference is quite big between `0.968` and `1.1334039`.

Comment: Other question related to this one on how to use this code with my real data. With my real data I have to use intervals of time of 57 seconds instead of 2 seconds. For this, is it enough to change `DateTime+2` for `DateTime+2`?. Another question is what happens if for example, I have a DateTime in my dataframe df for which there is not data in the `Activity` dataframe. Will it appear an `NA` for VeDBA and RMS in this row or the whole code won't work?

Comment: Can you start a new R session and copy and run the code under data section in my post?

Comment: You can change from 2 to 57. It should be an NA.

Comment: I added the output I get in your post, was it what you wanted? I closed and opened again my R session and I still get the same output! Have you run again yours and checked what you get using your proposed code?

Comment: i  am still getting the same output. I am wondering if its related to system locale. `Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252"`

Comment: One extra doubt, what does `(1L:3L) := NULL` mean? In my real dataframe, in addition to having to calculate RMS and VeDBA for 57 second intervals, I have 16 different `ID`s instead of 3. I wonder if I should change this part of the code or some other part...

Comment: no extra code to handle ID. `(1L:3L) := NULL` deletes the first 3 columns of the data.table

Comment: Hi again @chinsoon12. I found one of the problems. It seems that your `Activity` dataframe is different from mine even after using `set.seed()`. For instance, `Activity[1,]` in my dataframe gives `1 2017-08-05 14:03:55.299  A -0.39 -0.11 0.16` and in yours gives `1 2017-08-05 14:03:55.299  A  0.01  0.82 -0.56`. So we weren't using the same data and that's why our results weren't even close each other.

Comment: I added to your post some doubts I got after using your code proposed. After being sure that I am using the same data than you (I use `raw data` added by you), I've realized that the results that I get with your code are different from what I get manually. Regarding VeDBA values, it is curious because for the first 3 rows the values change slightly using your code or using my "manual" code, but for the last 3 rows the values are exactly the same. For `RMS` values, your values are completely different from mines. Can you help me to guess why those differences?

Comment: You might want to simplify the example. For example using integers for DateTime and a smaller range for joining